# ctrl drag outlet to baseview

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder

i have 4 views that extend one base view. I'd like to define some properties of outlets inside my base view and ctrl drag the "connection" on the final view to the outlet defined in the base view.
Is this possible with IB? When setting the FileOwner of the final View to it's class, those properties defined in the base class do not show up.

_thanks

Comment: I think it should be possible but if it's not you can always create a UIViewController with the size of your base view and treat it's view as a base view. It's a common missconception that UIViewController is suitable only for whole-screen purposes.

Comment: Now this would probably work, but i don't think it's the "way it's thought to be". I try to learn iOS at the moment, so i'd like to do it as it's supposed to be done :)

But i can't belive there is no way to do this with IB.

Comment: Haa found it :) you have to select the base class manualy in the assistent editor. The (and only when selected the base class) you can drag/drop the outlet to the property defined in the class.

Comment: i agree - but it's also true that xcode doesn't offer you to automatically add xib to UIView (as it does in UIViewController case).